# Update select lists in ng-repeat with the predefined value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have select list column in ng-repeat.I have checkbox column in each repeat as well.
Say I have a pre-defined tax value which should be updated to the select list items for the rows I have checked.

How can I achieve this ? Using ng-model in select list updates all of the items i.e full column instead of the selected rows.

Here is the code.

```js
 $scope.data = {
  products: [
  { name: "Product #1", description: "A product",
  category: "Category #1", price: 100, isChecked:false,
  taxList: [
   {label: "Vat 20%"},
   {label: "Vat 30%"},
   {label: "Vat 40%"}
   ]
   },
  { name: "Product #2", description: "A product",
  category: "Category #1", price: 110, isChecked:false,
  taxList: [
   {label: "Vat 20%"},
   {label: "Vat 30%"},
   {label: "Vat 40%"}
   ]
   },
  { name: "Product #3", description: "A product",
  category: "Category #2", price: 210, isChecked:false,
  taxList: [
   {label: "Vat 20%"},
   {label: "Vat 30%"},
   {label: "Vat 40%"}
   ]
   },
  { name: "Product #4", description: "A product",
  category: "Category #3", price: 202, isChecked:false,
  taxList: [
   {label: "Vat 20%"},
   {label: "Vat 30%"},
   {label: "Vat 40%"}
   ]
   }]
 };

 angular.forEach($scope.data.products, function(product){
  product.taxList.unshift({label: "Select Tax"});
  $scope.selectedTax = product.taxList[0].label;
 });

 $scope.updateListTax  = function(){
  $scope.preDefinedTax = "Vat 40%";
  angular.forEach($scope.data.products, function(product){
   if(product.isChecked){
    $scope.selectedTax = $scope.preDefinedTax;
   }
  });
 }
```

```css
ul,li{
 list-style:none;
}
.group:after{
 content: '';
 display: table;
 clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <section>
     <div class="group">
      <div class="col-sm-6"><strong>Product Details</strong></div>
      <div class="col-sm-6"><strong>Tax</strong></div>
     </div>
     <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in data.products" class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-6">
        <span class="col-sm-1">
         <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.isChecked">
        </span>
        <span class="col-sm-11">{{item.name}}</span>
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-6">
        <select ng-options="tax.label as tax.label for tax in item.taxList" ng-model="selectedTax"></select>
       </div>
      </li>
     </ul>
     <button ng-click="updateListTax()" class="btn btn-default">save</button>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 1):

The selectedTax is in the parent scope so it's the same for every product. Add a selectedTax key to every item object and do use ng-model.

```
$scope.data = {
    products: [
        { name: "Product #1", description: "A product",
        category: "Category #1", price: 100, isChecked:false,
        taxList: [
            {label: "Vat 20%"},
            {label: "Vat 30%"},
            {label: "Vat 40%"}
            ]
         },
        selectedTax: null
        ...
angular.forEach($scope.data.products, function(product){
    product.taxList.unshift({label: "Select Tax"});
    product.selectedTax = product.taxList[0].label;
});

$scope.updateListTax  = function(){
    $scope.preDefinedTax = "Vat 40%";
    angular.forEach($scope.data.products, function(product){
        if(product.isChecked){
            product.selectedTax = $scope.preDefinedTax;
        }
    });
}
```

HTML

```
<select ng-options="tax.label as tax.label for tax in item.taxList" ng-model="item.selectedTax"></select>
```

Comment: Yes you are right. If I could checkbox's isChecked in my list,  I sure could have added selectedTax to it. I just wasn't sure about setting isChecked manually (practically coming from server side). So kept muddling if it could be handled in front-end alone. This much can be communicated between server-side and client side! Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-model="item.isChecked$index"` this will create a separate scope variable for each and every checkbox in the ng-repeat.